# My code in kotlin classes is automatically replaced by some XML code in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, gradle, kotlin

I have a project for Android, in Android Studio. For some reason, code in my kotlin files is automatically replaced by some strange xml code.

I don't have any idea why this is happening

For example code below:

```
package com.alex.willtrip.objectbox.helpers

import com.alex.willtrip.objectbox.ObjectBox
import com.alex.willtrip.objectbox.converters.LocalDateConverter
import io.objectbox.Box
import io.objectbox.annotation.Convert
import io.objectbox.annotation.Entity
import io.objectbox.annotation.Id
import io.objectbox.annotation.Index
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDate

@Entity
class DateEntity (@Id var id: Long = 0, @Index val link: Long,
                 @Convert(converter = LocalDateConverter::class, dbType = Long::class)
                 val date: LocalDate)

class DateSaver {

    private fun getBox (): Box<DateEntity> {
        return ObjectBox.boxStore.boxFor(DateEntity::class.java)
    }

    fun getDate (link: Long): LocalDate? {
        return getBox().query().equal(DateEntity_.link, link).build().findUnique()?.date
    }

    fun saveDate (link: Long, date: LocalDate) {
        val id = getBox().query().equal(DateEntity_.link, link).build().findUnique()?.id ?: 0
        getBox().put(DateEntity(id, link, date))
    }
}
```

is replaced by code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="CMakeSettings">
    <configurations>
      <configuration PROFILE_NAME="Debug" CONFIG_NAME="Debug" />
    </configurations>
  </component>
  <component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_7" project-jdk-name="1.8" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK">
    <output url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/build/classes" />
  </component>
  <component name="ProjectType">
    <option name="id" value="Android" />
  </component>
</project>
```

Comment: I have also faced the same issue, maybe  UTF 8 conversion issue and try to relocate your project.

Answer (score 0):

There's a known bug in Android Studio where sometimes your project files will get randomly mixed with one another and just ruin your entire project.

I'm not sure if this is the case here, but to solve this I'd suggest you try deleting the contents of this folder:

`C:\Users\[your-username]\.AndroidStudio3.5\system\caches`

The `.AndroidStudio3.5` folder might have a different version number.

After you're cleared the folder, restart Android Studio.

If this doesn't fix your project files, your other options is to restore them using your VCS, if you're used one.

Comment: I experienced this sometime ago, mine got mixed up each time my laptop shuts down in the middle of build or syncing due to power failure, courtesy of a faulty battery. After replacing, I'm yet to experience it again.